# Why do I keep getting "Not a JSON Array"?

Tags: java, json, illegalstateexception

I have an app that uses `SOAP and REST service`. First data is pulled using SOAP then using REST. Now I want to show data using JSF but I keep getting "Not a JSON Array". I don't understand what is the problem.

```
korisnici = new ArrayList<>();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        KorisnikREST klijentKor = new KorisnikREST();
        String jsonStr = klijentKor.getJson();
        System.out.println("Get daje odgovor :" + jsonStr);
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(jsonStr).getAsJsonObject();
        System.out.println(jsonObject);      
        JsonArray json = (jsonObject.get("odgovor")).getAsJsonArray();
```

The result that I get:

```
{"odgovor":"[{\"id\":1,\"ime\":\"ap\",\"korisnickoIme\":\"Antonija\",\"lozinka\":\"Pofuk\",\"prezime\":\"ap\"},{\"id\":2,\"ime\":\"s\",\"korisnickoIme\":\"Sandro\",\"lozinka\":\"Sadnric\",\"prezime\":\"s\"}]","status":"OK"}
```

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Array

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The response is not valid JSON: the array is enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: the value of odgovor is string not json array

Comment: @jalynn2: I think the response *is* valid JSON; it's just that the field of interest is not an array, but rather a string that contains JSON that contains an array.

Comment: So I should parse jsonObject first as String?

Comment: @ruakh: Yes, you are correct. I should have said it is not a valid array. user10807076: you should parse the value of "odgover"

Answer (score 0):

This Json is organized really weirdly as mentioned in the comments.

try something like this:

```
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(jsonStr).getAsJsonObject();          
    JsonArray json = new JsonParser().parse(jsonObject.get("odgovor")).getAsJsonArray()
```